# steps to convert single databse to utf8mb4 in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-administration, utf8mb4, character-set

i want to change the character set of a table in mysql database to utf8mb4 without changing in config file .i dont want entire database to use utf8mb4 .

i already changed the database,table and procedures character set and collation to utf8mb4

```
alter database DBNAME CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
alter table tblname CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

i want to store emojis in mysql databse without changing the entire database to utf8mb4 .please help me

Comment: Anywhere you want to store emoji type characters you'll need to convert it.

Comment: hi @tadman can you help me out necessary step in details .even after converting character set i am unable to store

Comment: That really doesn't tell us where the problem is. The list of necessary steps starts with giving us something to work with, like an error or *anything* that helps narrow down the problem.

Comment: @tadman even after doing this commands 

alter database DBNAME CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci; 


alter table tblname CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

after changing the charcter set of procedures involved to utf8mb4 does not solve the issue .

what else required ?

Comment: Even after doing that...what? It's important to explain what you're seeing, because we can only guess otherwise.

Comment: @tadman i am getting ???? in database instead of emojis

Comment: Unless you can describe this in terms we can reproduce, I've got no idea what you're asking for. What emojis? How are you inserting them? Are you sure you're using UTF-8?

Comment: @tadman may i know what exact information you need to help me out ?

Comment: #1 is an error message. #2 is some SQL that reproduces the problem you have *including* how you're trying to insert.